# R: plotting - visualizing the common time period of events in a 24 hours timeframe from multiple dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have dataframes of events captured and i am finding a way to visualize which time period (1hr window) does these events usually occur in a 24 hours timeframe.

I'm only interested in the event starttime.
So x-axis of the plot should be a 24 hours series, breaks at 1hour.
and y-axis would be the different dataframes represented by a geom_point or something
And I like to seek advice how can I do this from multiple dataframes.

df1

```
        TimeStamp_start         TimeStamp_end  Fab23.A_start   Fab23.A_end 
1   2020-03-01 21:56:00   2020-03-01 21:58:00       38.67555      184.4875  
2   2020-03-02 20:48:00   2020-03-02 20:50:00       31.98126      186.0867  
3   2020-03-03 18:14:00   2020-03-03 18:16:00       41.42305      189.7806  
4   2020-03-04 17:50:00   2020-03-04 17:52:00       36.79726      190.0810  
5   2020-03-05 16:58:00   2020-03-05 17:00:00       39.70075      189.8803  
.
.
.
```

df2

```
        TimeStamp_start         TimeStamp_end    Fab7.A_start    Fab7.A_end
1   2020-03-03 05:20:00   2020-03-03 05:22:00        39.98769      141.9722 
2   2020-03-06 02:04:00   2020-03-06 02:06:00        40.59314      189.5027 
3   2020-03-08 17:18:00   2020-03-08 17:20:00        47.79272      191.8802 
4   2020-03-10 16:00:00   2020-03-10 16:02:00        42.69026      190.4804 
.
.
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to look like a dumbbell chart, but instead of the dumbbell it's presented by geom_point in density.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a dummy varialbe indicating the `df` and then bind the `dfs` together and then plot them:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
              ~TimeStamp_start,        ~TimeStamp_end, ~Fab23.A_start, ~Fab23.A_end,
         "2020-03-01 21:56:00", "2020-03-01 21:58:00",       38.67555,     184.4875,
         "2020-03-02 20:48:00", "2020-03-02 20:50:00",       31.98126,     186.0867,
         "2020-03-03 18:14:00", "2020-03-03 18:16:00",       41.42305,     189.7806,
         "2020-03-04 17:50:00", "2020-03-04 17:52:00",       36.79726,      190.081,
         "2020-03-05 16:58:00", "2020-03-05 17:00:00",       39.70075,     189.8803
         )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
              ~TimeStamp_start,        ~TimeStamp_end, ~Fab7.A_start, ~Fab7.A_end,
         "2020-03-03 05:20:00", "2020-03-03 05:22:00",      39.98769,    141.9722,
         "2020-03-06 02:04:00", "2020-03-06 02:06:00",      40.59314,    189.5027,
         "2020-03-08 17:18:00", "2020-03-08 17:20:00",      47.79272,    191.8802,
         "2020-03-10 16:00:00", "2020-03-10 16:02:00",      42.69026,    190.4804
         )

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggridges)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(TimeStamp_start = ymd_hms(TimeStamp_start),
         df_dummy = "df1")

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(TimeStamp_start = ymd_hms(TimeStamp_start),
         df_dummy = "df2")

dfs <- bind_rows(df1,df2)

dfs %>% 
  mutate(by_hour = hour(TimeStamp_start)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = by_hour, y = df_dummy)) +
  geom_density_ridges()
```

The problem with this plot is that the density expands past 0 and 24. We could cut the density or indicate that the data does not expand past 0 and 24 with a graph like this (customized x axis tick marks and show where actual data is):

```
dfs %>% 
  mutate(by_hour = hour(TimeStamp_start)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = by_hour, y = df_dummy)) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height = 0.01, jittered_points = TRUE,
                      position = position_points_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0),
                      point_shape = "|", point_size = 4,
                      alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:24)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to plot the starting time of each event. Depending on the frequency and number of events, you might end up overplotting and something like a histogram or density plot would be a better visualization option. However, I use something like this to find periods of missing sampling in my own data. Let's start with just a single dataframe:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


## generate some random start date/time data
df1 <- tibble(start_time = as.POSIXlt("2020-03-01 21:56:00") + rnorm(100, 0, 604800))


## create a numeric hour/minute variable 
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(y_pos = "df1", ## this provides a y variable to map in ggplot
         start_hour = hour(start_time) + (minute(start_time)/60)) ## decimal hour.min

## plot it
ggplot(df1) +
  geom_point(aes(start_hour, y_pos),
             alpha = 0.9,
             shape = 124) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,24),
                     breaks = 0:24)
```

[image: rugplot]

If you have multiple dataframes, it is a matter of getting everything tidied up and creating a single dataframe. I would create some kind of categorical variable in each dataframe and just bind the rows.

```r
df2 <- tibble(start_time = as.POSIXlt("2020-03-01 21:56:00") + rnorm(100, 0, 604800)) %>%
  mutate(y_pos = "df2",
         start_hour = hour(start_time) + (minute(start_time)/60))

df1 <- df1 %>%
  bind_rows(df2)

ggplot(df1) +
  geom_point(aes(start_hour, y_pos),
             alpha = 0.9,
             shape = 124) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,24),
                     breaks = 0:24)
```

[image: rugplot2]